# Linear model: comparing predictive power of two different measurement methods

Tags: r, linear-regression, mixed-models

I'm interested in predicting `Y` and am studying different two measurement techniques `X1` and `X2`. It could be for instance that I want to predict the tastiness of a banana, either by measuring how long it has been lying on the table, or by measuring the number of brown spots on the banana.

I want to know which one of the measuring techniques is better, should I choose to perform only one.

I can create a linear model in R:

```
m1 = lm(Y ~ X1)
m2 = lm(Y ~ X2)
```

Now let's say `X1` is a superior predictor of banana tastiness than `X2`. When calculating the R^2 of the two models, the R^2 of model `m1` is clearly higher than model `m2`. Before writing a paper on how method `X1` is better than `X2`, I want to have some sort of indication that the difference is not by chance, possibly in the form of a p-value.

How would one go about this? How to do it when I'm using different brands of bananas and move to a Linear Mixed Effect model that incoporates banana brand as a random effect?

Comment: I might compare [mean squared prediction errors](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20741/11849).

Comment: Comparing models using `anova` function: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/53312/8464

Comment: You can only compare models with `anova` when they're nested models, which these are not.  The requested testing would probably best be done using AIC.

Comment: @John - absolutely right, data is different - so ANOVA doesn't apply.

Comment: Moved this question to stats.stackexchange.com where it belongs. Sorry to have wasted your time. Thanks for your comments so far.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if didn't understand you right. So far as I understood, it's simple basic statistics question, not R.

You put them together in 1 regression. p-value for each coefficient reveals whether they are significant or not. You can also but banana brand as a dummy (if there are not too many types). And do ANOVA tests.
Btw are both measurements techniques significant in separate models? What's R^2 of those models and combined model?
As for your problem, look to the definition of R^2, hope that will help :)

Comment: No, they want to compare models. Putting both predictors in one model, won't tell you, which is the better predictor on its own.

Comment: Then if both are significant separately, compare by R^2. So you can tell that m1 explains Y as some percentage, that is higher than in m2

Comment: Putting both predictors in a model tells us something if only one of them will have a significant pvalue..if both are significant those with the higher coefficient will be the one with the larger effect on the dependent variable. To compare models you could use AIC, but I do not think that in this case that's necessary...